# Java - Read excel, modify then save to a new file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have it currently working so that my application is generating the content, then saving the information into an excel file, this is working as expected using the below code

```
public void writeExcel(ClassManager cm, String fn, ErrorManager em) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // Get classes
    classes = cm.getClasses();
    String fileName = (!"".equals(fn)) ? fn : "temp.xlsx";
   
    // Create Rows
    setupRows();
    
    File currDir = new File(".");
    String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
    String fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + fileName;

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    workbook.close();
}
```

the setupRow function calls several other functions, all setup the same as below

```
public void setupRowTemplateName() {
    int start = 2;
    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
        
    for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
        // Get class and template details
        Classes c = classes.get(i);
        Template t = c.getTemplate();
        
        // Create cell
        Cell cell = row.createCell(start);
        
        // Set contents
        if(t != null) {
            cell.setCellValue(t.getName());
        }
        
        start++;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to adjust the saving so that it takes an excel file, adds the information to that, then saves as a new file (i.e: Take file "Codes Template.xlsx", add data, save as another filename.

So far I have

```
public void writeExcelReplace(ClassManager cm, String fn, ErrorManager em) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File currDir = new File(".");
    String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
    String fileLocationOpen = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + "Codes Template.xlsx";
    
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocationOpen));
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    // Get classes
    classes = cm.getClasses();
    String fileName = (!"".equals(fn)) ? fn : "temp.xlsx";
   
    // Create Rows
    setupRows();
    
    String fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + fileName;

    inputStream.close();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    workbook.close();
}
```

This is taking the content from the "template" file and saving it to the new file, but none of the content from setupRows is being added

Comment: This is not even close to a minimal working example. How is anyone supposed to reproduce your problem without having full information about the code and - most importantly - the library you are using?

Comment: So basically you want to open an existing Excel file, add a row (or rows) to it, and save it as a different Excel file. Is that correct? And are you using [Apache] POI?

Comment: Yeah, i want to open the file, add information, the save as another filename. First and last part works, adding the information doesn't. Using apache poi

Comment: Can you show the file contents before the additions and also what the file contents should be after the additions?

Comment: Basically A2-A14 contain section headings, then additional columns contain the data c2-c14, d2-d14